# Share Variables between Methods in a Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails controller that has 2 methods. Both Methods use some of the same variables and I'm wondering how I can refactor this into either a method in the Model of somewhere in the controller to make them more reusable than they are now.

```
class ChartsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :company_id

  def service_level
    latest_date = Invoice.where(:account_id => @company.accounts).maximum(:invc_date)
    invoices_filter = { :invoices => { :invc_date => (latest_date - 3.months)..latest_date } }

    invoices = Invoice.where({:account_id => @company.accounts}.merge(invoices_filter))
    details = InvoiceDetail.joins(:type).where(:invoice_id => invoices)
    freight_details = details.where(:invoice_detail_types => { :category => 'freight' })

    freight_groups = freight_details.group(:family).select("family, count(distinct package_id), sum(base_charge + discount)")


    vol_data = {}
    spend_data = {}

    @charts = {}

     @charts[:service_analysis] = {
      :vol_data => Hash[freight_groups.map { |row| [InvoiceDetailFamily[row.family].name, row.count.to_i] }],
      :spend_data => Hash[freight_groups.map { |row| [InvoiceDetailFamily[row.family].name, row.sum.to_f] }]
    }

    render partial: 'service_level'
  end

  def weight_summary

    latest_date = Invoice.where(:account_id => @company.accounts).maximum(:invc_date)
    invoices_filter = { :invoices => { :invc_date => (latest_date - 3.months)..latest_date } }

    invoices = Invoice.where({:account_id => @company.accounts}.merge(invoices_filter))
    details = InvoiceDetail.joins(:type).where(:invoice_id => invoices)
    freight_details = details.where(:invoice_detail_types => { :category => 'freight' })
    packages = freight_details.joins(:package, :invoice)



    vol_data = {}
    spend_data = {}
    packages.group(:zone).select("zone, count(distinct package_id), sum(base_charge + discount)").each do |row|
      case row.zone
        when '02'..'08', '002'..'008', '102'..'108', '132'..'138', '202'..'208', '242'..'248', '302'..'308'
          zg = row.zone[-1]
        when '09'..'17', '124'..'126', '224'..'226'
          zg = 'AK/HI/PR'
        else
          zg = 'Import/Export'
      end
      vol_data[zg] = (vol_data[zg] || 0) + row.count.to_i
      spend_data[zg] = (spend_data[zg] || 0) + row.sum.to_f
    end
    @charts = {}

    @charts[:weight_analysis] = {
      :vol_data => Hash[(vol_data.sort_by {|key, value| key.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i})],
      :spend_data => Hash[(spend_data.sort_by {|key, value| key.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i})]
    }


    render partial: 'weight_summary'
  end
end
```

Comment: How about `before_filter :set_common_variables`?

Comment: Would I put this in the application_controller or as a private method?

Comment: Private method on that controller

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use a model class method for processing data. for example

```
freight_details = details.where(:invoice_detail_types => { :category => 'freight' })

freight_groups = freight_details.group(:family).select("family, count(distinct package_id), sum(base_charge + discount)")


vol_data = {}
spend_data = {}

@charts = {}

 @charts[:service_analysis] = {
  :vol_data => Hash[freight_groups.map { |row| [InvoiceDetailFamily[row.family].name, row.count.to_i] }],
  :spend_data => Hash[freight_groups.map { |row| [InvoiceDetailFamily[row.family].name, row.sum.to_f] }]
}
```

could be moved to a model class method that returns `charts`. In the same way you can refactor your second method. Any kind of business logic and data proccessing should be handled in models

Moreover I can see there are too many unused local variables are there in controller. The controller should be thin as much as possible.

Comment: +1 , every processing should go to model, so that it can be shared across controllers.Fat models and thin controllers +1

Answer (score 1):

Use concept like decorator

```
module Chart
   extend self
   def service_analysis(freight_groups, freight_groups)

   end
end
class ChartsController < ApplicationController
    @chart = Chart.service_analysis(freight_groups, freight_groups)
end
```

notes: do not put calculation code in view, it's slow

Answer (score 1):

If you decided to keep it within the controller, then try this:

```
class ChartsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :company_id
  before_filter :load_data, :only => [:service_level, weight_summary]

  def service_level
    freight_groups = @freight_details.group(:family).select("family, count(distinct package_id), sum(base_charge + discount)")

    @charts = {}
    @charts[:service_analysis] = {
      :vol_data => Hash[freight_groups.map { |row| [InvoiceDetailFamily[row.family].name, row.count.to_i] }],
      :spend_data => Hash[freight_groups.map { |row| [InvoiceDetailFamily[row.family].name, row.sum.to_f] }]
    }

    render partial: 'service_level'
  end

  def weight_summary
    packages = @freight_details.joins(:package, :invoice)

    vol_data = {}
    spend_data = {}

    packages.group(:zone).select("zone, count(distinct package_id), sum(base_charge + discount)").each do |row|
      case row.zone
        when '02'..'08', '002'..'008', '102'..'108', '132'..'138', '202'..'208', '242'..'248', '302'..'308'
          zg = row.zone[-1]
        when '09'..'17', '124'..'126', '224'..'226'
          zg = 'AK/HI/PR'
        else
          zg = 'Import/Export'
      end
      vol_data[zg] = (vol_data[zg] || 0) + row.count.to_i
      spend_data[zg] = (spend_data[zg] || 0) + row.sum.to_f
    end
    @charts = {}

    @charts[:weight_analysis] = {
      :vol_data => Hash[(vol_data.sort_by {|key, value| key.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i})],
      :spend_data => Hash[(spend_data.sort_by {|key, value| key.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i})]
    }

    render partial: 'weight_summary'
  end

  private

  def load_data
    latest_date = Invoice.where(:account_id => @company.accounts).maximum(:invc_date)
    invoices_filter = { :invoices => { :invc_date => (latest_date - 3.months)..latest_date } }
    invoices = Invoice.where({:account_id => @company.accounts}.merge(invoices_filter))
    details = InvoiceDetail.joins(:type).where(:invoice_id => invoices)
    @freight_details = details.where(:invoice_detail_types => { :category => 'freight' })
  end

end
```

The instance variable @freight_details will be available in both methods. The before_filter will execute the load_data method only for these two methods.

Good Luck!